# Load resistance change detection

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

I am trying to detect load resistance changes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3oEP2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to monitor R load resistance (glow plug).

PWM duty cycle (max) varies from 100% when V1 is 1.2V to 3.7% (8V)

I need to keep the temperature of the glow plug constant. The actual resistance of the glow plug is unknown (0.2 to 0.3R when cold). On the start-up I measure the voltage of the power supply - and power the glow accordingly (glow plus are 1.2V - for higher voltages the PWM duty cycle is k  = (V1)^2/(1.2)^2) ). When the engine is running I need to keep the glow temperature constant. So I need to detect changes in glow plug resistance - if it goes down (glow is getting colder) I need to increase the k, when it goes up (glow is getting warmer) I need to reduce the k.

Users can use any battery packs up to 8V.

The problem is that those changes are extremely low. For the particular V1 it quite easy to create the circuit which amplifies them (I was experimenting with the low pass filter and differential amplifier).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftBN06.png)</sup>

But I can't find any way to make it universal for the different V1.

I don't need to measure the actual resistance - I just need to detect the change of the resistance (if is going down I need to increase the duty cycle and vice versa)

Comment: Your question is inconsistent with itself.  You are asking about detecting load resistance, but the description talks about wanting to adjust for supply voltage changes.  Closing until the question makes sense.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think it is clear, he is already adjusting PWM duty for supply voltage, he wants to refine the PWM duty depending on the load resistance to give constant power.

Comment: @icy: First, he said nothing about constant power.  Second, he gave specific duty cycles for specific values of V1.  Third, the load is always 200 mOhm, so doesn't change.  Note how the schematic *does* show V1 changing.  Since duty cycle is only a function of V1 and the load doesn't change, good parts of the question make no sense (or are very badly written).  Either way, closing is the only thing to do for the question in this state.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - yes I gave the particular PWM - but it is the constant maximum power for the glow plug (from the euqaion above) multiplied by the coefficient  found experimental way

Comment: @OlinLathrop The load isn't fixed to that value, as the resistance gets hot, it goes up, at a certain temperature it's "the right value" and needs to be kept there, still pretty clear to me.

Comment: @PeterJ: Is a micro controller allowed or are you trying to do everything with analog circuitry?

Comment: I use micro of course. This is only the analog part of the circuit. I tried the "digital way" using the ADC, but unfortunately the voltage changes are so small and the V1 can be everything from 1.2 to 8V.  Actually I need to process the output voltage to make those changes large enough to have a reliable ADC readings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of what the solution might look like. Using some clever software, you can use this to stabilize the duty cycle on some particular value of resistance (current flow) no matter what the battery voltage is. You can sample the current during the ON state to make sure you're still close, then increase and decrease the duty cycle from there.

I just winged this circuit together from memory, so please read up on 'constant current circuits' to see the specifics of how to design the op-amp circuit and how to get the gain you need and how to select a correctly sized sense resistor.

Hope this helps!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwHorJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Most obvious one :) I have started from this one  one , but the simulation was giving erratic results. Now i have cheched the circuit in the LTSpice and I have found that circuit was open. Of course it will work with small amendment - i will add a low pass filter as the current in the circuit is not a rectangular one - and it is quite difficult to find maximum and minimum points.

Comment: I think you should sample during the ON times, rather than trying to average over the duty cycle. You should make your PWM frequency high enough that the resistance doesn't vary significantly.